# Editing a parent object from one of many child objects

Tags: edit, relations

Let's say you have a `foo`. Any given `foo` can be bought in multiple ways - loans over different terms, leases, etc. The `foo` has certain properties which effect the payment scenarios, such as the MSRP, the selling price, the shipping cost, etc.

I have a screen that shows all the possible scenarios for a set of given `foos` in which a customer might be interested in purchasing. Let's call this `Screen 1`.

[image: Payment Scenarios by Foo]

Each payment scenario has its own screen that you click into with additional details and further options you can edit (such as the term, configuring different taxing parameters, etc.). Let's call this `Screen 2`.

[image: Individual Payment Scenario]

If the selling price, shipping, etc. of a `foo` needs to be edited, the obvious place to do it is on the top level, `Screen 1`, when listing the `foos` and the given payment scenario overviews. However, a concern has been raised that if a user is already in a payment scenario - `Screen 2`, they have to click back to the `foo` overview in order to edit this information. This is non-ideal, as it takes extra time and clicks for the user, interrupting their workflow.

On the other hand, we make this information visible on the child screens - `Screen 2`. We can make it editable from these screens, instead of just viewable. However, I'm concerned that doing so will be confusing. For example:

- When editing the Selling Price of the `foo` from `Screen 2`, will the user know they are editing it for all other payment scenarios that pertain to that `foo`?
- Will they think they are just editing those details for that specific scenario?

  - If so, is there a (non-obtrusive) way to make it clear that this will effect the other payments?
- Is this even desirable? Is there a reason *not* to do this that overrides the additional ease-of-use?
- If we do implement it, is it better to remove the editing at the top level, to keep a single click-path to edit a given piece of information (a consistent complaint on our current design is that there are too many ways to complete a given action)?

Comment: Is the price of **foo** something that influences the decision to proceed to Payment? If so, breaking the workflow and editing it before continuing seems more important to me than ease-of-use.

Comment: How exactly is price of other "foos" edited, once one foo price is changed? is it linear like all of them have higher price for 50, or is something more complicated?

Answer (score 1):

**Screen 1** is not the obvious place for editing price/shipping for each foo, as you don't see such information on Screen 1 (according to mockup).

When a person is on a **Screen 2** (single Scenario) she has a chance to see a detailed information and this is the place to make a decision to edit it.

I assume some parameters to edit are **global** (will change all Scenarios) and some are **local** (will change specific Scenario). You can provide an **one** option to "Edit Foo A Super Edition". Once in *edit mode*, clearly separate which parameters are global and which apply only to a local Scenario.

**Alternative**

**Foo A Super Edition** - information on the Screen 1 could be divided from the start, separating global information from local per Scenario. Person could edit each.